# RPC connection fails

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, network, rpc

I launched my geth with those parameters :

`sudo geth --syncmode "light" --cache=2048 --datadir /mnt/ssd/ethereum --pprof.addr 0.0.0.0 --pprof`

It's running on a ubuntu server 20 on a raspberry pi 4.

When I try this :

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider

w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://192.168.1.29:8545'))
latest_block_num = w3.eth.blockNumber
tx_count = w3.eth.getBlockTransactionCount(latest_block_num)
print("lastest block {} with a tx_count of {}".format(latest_block_num, tx_count))
```

I get :

'requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.29', port=8545): Max retries exceeded'

are my launch parameters corrects?
Firewall is disabled on the ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('http://192.168.1.29:8545'));
```

you will need to use WebsocketProvider in order to subscribe to an event if you are using `version web3.js@1.x`